# How can I get the content of my database and not the index

Tags: php, mysql, database, indexing

I inserted the data into my MySQL database successfully, but my problem is that the result I get and I have inside my database is the index and not the actual content. I wrote the below code for one of the option in my php file. How can I get the content and not the index? Is the problem in the SQL statement or in the PHP code? For example, if the user choose the first option from the popup menu then I will get No 1 instead of the `serviceType = "Database Type"`

```
Finding ServiceType Title   RootCause   RiskRating  Impact  Efforts Likelihood  
1   2   gg  AC  1   1   1   1    gg  gg  gg 1
7   1   kkkk    Cfm 1   1   2   1    kkkkk   kkkkk   kkkkkk 1
    1

<?php
    mysql_select_db("ers_1", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ServiceType_ID, ServiceType_Name FROM servicetype_lookup  ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['ServiceType_ID'];
        $value = $row['ServiceType_Name'];
        echo "<option value='$id'>$value</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just realized two people got the the edit while I was editing it! Wow!

Comment: "inside my database is index"? huh?

Comment: Seeing as your a new user, please consider marking the answer that you found most helpful as "correct answer" when you work through this issue. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: dude whats the problem of your code? it looks fine..

Answer (score 2):

Please check your query in an SQL tool to make sure you're actually receiving data for that query. If there is no data, that may be causing your issue.

Also, use:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

instead of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

in your `while()` statement to get the output you are looking for.

Good luck!

Just as a thought, you need to consider moving off of the `mysql_` commands in favor of the MySQLi and PDO libraries.

Look here: [Choosing a MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: I changed the while loop as you suggested but there is no difference .. ??maybe there is wrong in the SQL Statement or not I mean I should complete it and put where word and the rest ??

Comment: See if you can run that query on the command line or in something like PHPMyAdmin so you can be certain you're `SELECT`ing real data.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is your friend, when it comes to testing queries :)

Comment: fetch_array() and fetch_assoc() will BOTH returned indexed arrays as required for the rest of the code - so this is not the correct answer. Not marking down as you've suggested PDO or mysqli - but the main answer is really not relevent.)

Comment: David please I still didn't solve the problem .. What shall I do ?

Comment: I would stop using `mysql_` functions, first, and follow the instructions in the link I put in my answer. I guarantee if you switch to PDO or MySQLi you will not have a problem, assuming your database does not have a problem.